# How to filter dashboard based on quick filter values selected in Tableau ?

Tags: tableau-api

I'm having Dashboard-1 with the data source from SQL Server Table-A having columns
Col1,Col2,Col3

Now, i'm creating a new dashboard-2 with data source as Table-B having columns Col1,Col4,Col5.

But Col1 which is common in both these tables doesn't have common data.

Eg. Col1 from Table-A is having records till 100 and Table-B is having records from 101.Also, the data is not static, its keeps on increasing in Table-B , Table-A is no longer populating but we need the data from it.

**Problem1--** How to merge two column as single column for filter in Tableau

**Problem2--** in the dashboard i need to show single filter as a union of Col1 from both tables, if user select value <100 then Dashboard-1 will open otherwise Dashboard-2.

Can someone provide me a correct approach.

Answer (score -1):

1) Instead of merging after you have brought the data in, try merging the data using SQL UNION.

2) If that's not possible, do the same after importing both the datasets into Tableau. For an example, try from this [official link](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/joining_tables.htm#integration)

3) Try different Joins to see which one works for merging your table columns:

[image: Available joins]

4) If all the above fails, try setting up an Action Filter explained in this [link](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/actions.htm). Essentially you have to use Tiled Containers instead of Floating Containers and set up a action filter using a custom Parameter. This custom Parameter will help display Dashboard 1 when user selects <100 in the filter(for example) and Dashboard 2 when user selects >100(again example)

Comment: ...i think filtering of dashboard using action will work, but the primary step is how to combine the common columns into one